# Escape HTML Chars In the Pre Tag

Tags: php, html, replace, pre

I've installed a syntax highlighter, but in order for it to work, the tags must be written as `&lt;` and `&gt;`. What I need to do is replace all <'s with `&lt;` and >'s with `&gt;` but only inside the PRE tag.

So, in short, I want to escape all HTML characters inside of the pre tag.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I understand - are you trying to escape HTML code to display it on your page?

Comment: Yes, but only inside of the 'pre' tag.

Comment: Use `htmlspecialchars` on the tag's contents before you `echo` them. That's what you should be doing on *everything* before you echo it as well.

Comment: @Jon But how would I use it inside the pre tag only?

Comment: If you've used an MVC pattern then in your code you should know exactly where it outputs <pre> tags in the view and be able to add the `htmlspecialchars` quite simply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr

You need to parse the input HTML. Use the [`DOMDocument`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class to represent your document, parse the input, find all `<pre>` tags (using [`findElementsByTagName`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)) and escape their content.

### Code

Unfortunately, the DOM model is very low-level and forces you to iterate the child nodes of the `<pre>` tag yourself, to escape them. This looks as follows:

```
function escapeRecursively($node) {
    if ($node instanceof DOMText)
        return $node->textContent;

    $children = $node->childNodes;
    $content = "<$node->nodeName>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $children->length; $i += 1) {
        $child = $children->item($i);
        $content .= escapeRecursively($child);
    }

    return "$content</$node->nodeName>";
}
```

Now this function can be used to escape every `<pre>` node in the document:

```
function escapePreformattedCode($html) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);

    $pres = $doc->getElementsByTagName('pre');
    for ($i = 0; $i < $pres->length; $i += 1) {
        $node = $pres->item($i);

        $children = $node->childNodes;
        $content = '';
        for ($j = 0; $j < $children->length; $j += 1) {
            $child = $children->item($j);
            $content .= escapeRecursively($child);
        }
        $node->nodeValue = htmlspecialchars($content);
    }

    return $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

### Test

```
$string = '<h1>Test</h1> <pre>Some <em>interesting</em> text</pre>';
echo escapePreformattedCode($string);
```

Yields:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><h1>Test</h1> <pre>Some &lt;em&gt;interesting&lt;/em&gt; text</pre></body></html>
```

Note that a DOM always represents a *complete* document. Hence when the DOM parser gets a document fragment it fills in the missing information. This makes the output potentially different from the input.

Comment: Thanks! Works fine apart from one small bug. This is displayed when I load the page: /www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">

Comment: @Terry What page are you loading then? My example code displays just fine in a browser.

Comment: The view post page. I tested it out, it only occurs when I add your code.

Comment: @Terry Nevertheless, I’m fairly confident that the error is elsewhere and was just flushed out by adding my code. It works in isolation. I can’t really say any more since I don’t know your code.